# JSON.loads gives a string output when invoked in tornado handler

Tags: json, python-requests, tornado

I am passing some data to a tornado server handler which calls json.loads(request.body)
This is how request.body looks like:

```
b'"{\\"inputs\\": {\\"key1\\": \\"/9j/4QxgRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgA....... sVf/2Q==\\"}}"'
```

When I call json.loads on this request.body this is what the output looks like

```
payload = json.loads(request.body)
print(payload)
{"inputs": {"key1": "/9j/4QxgRXhpZgAATU.....rsVf/2Q=="}}
print(type(payload)) # <class 'str'>
payload2 = json.loads(payload)
print(type(payload2 )) # <class 'dict'>
```

I am not sure why the output of json.loads is str

This is the request body I am passing

```
with open("ee", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

x = {"inputs": {"key1": encoded_string.decode("utf-8")}}
<request_session>.post(<HOST>, json=json.dumps(x))
```

How can I change my request body such that when json.loads is called on my request.body, I recieve a dictionary

The handler is built in tornado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you're receiving is json encoded **twice**. So you'll need to decode it twice on the server to get the dict.

The problem is the way you're sending the data from the client. If you [see the docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) of `requests`, the `json` argument should be a **json serializable object**, not already serialized object.

That means `requests` is also encoding your json data once more.

Try passing the dict without json encoding:

```
<request_session>.post(<HOST>, json=x)
```